# Not implemented alter command for SQL ALTER TABLE "annotator_annotationmodel" ADD COLUMN "hospital_id" int NOT NULL

Tags: python, sql, django, backend

I'm getting this error after doing migrate in Django rest framework backend server.

models.py file

```
class Hostipal(models.Model):
    hospitalId = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    hospitalName = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    hospitalAddress = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hospitalName

class AnnotationModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    model_path = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hostipal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ModelPool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    modelsList = models.ManyToManyField(AnnotationModel, related_name="modelpool")
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hostipal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

What I am trying to build:

1. Every hospital has many AnnotationModels and ModelPools
2. Each AnnotationModel may belong to many model pools
3. Hence AnnotationModel has a hospital foreign key and ModelPool has a hospital foreign key and AnnotationModel ManyToMany column

Can we implement this using any other techniques?

Detailed error:

```
python3 manage.py migrate       
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, annotator, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
This version of djongo does not support "NULL, NOT NULL column validation check" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using CONSTRAINT" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name...This version of djongo does not support "COLUMN DROP NOT NULL " fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "DROP CASCADE" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using KEY" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using REFERENCES" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
Not implemented alter command for SQL ALTER TABLE "annotator_annotationmodel" ADD COLUMN "hospital_id" int NOT NULL
  Applying annotator.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 783, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 875, in parse
    raise e
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 856, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 888, in _alter
    query = AlterQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 425, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 435, in parse
    self._add(statement)
  File "/Users/gamemaster/GitHub/DMP_Backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 598, in _add
    raise SQLDecodeError(err_key=tok.value,
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

        Keyword: int
        Sub SQL: ALTER TABLE "annotator_annotationmodel" ADD COLUMN "hospital_id" int NOT NULL
        FAILED SQL: ('ALTER TABLE "annotator_annotationmodel" ADD COLUMN "hospital_id" int NOT NULL',)
        Params: ([],)
        Version: 1.3.4

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Comment: Remove all stuff not needed to get the error. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: The error is because of using hospital as foreign key in both AnnotationModel and ModelPool.